# Mouse leave jquery issue

Tags: jquery

I have this navigation menu, let's say **Black** that has a class of **testClass**.

When you hover it, the container itself will show (slide down).

The problem is, when I mouse hover **from** the menu **to** the container itself with the same class as the navigation that's been shown, the container slide up (hide the contents).

What I want to happen is, when I mouse hover to **black** the container will show up, when I mouse hover to the container that has the same class with the navigation menu, the container itself will remain shown until I mouse leave outside of a certain class which is **testClass**

Hope you guys understand it.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLpHE/) of it.

and this is the code that I'm using since I've been asked to put a code by SO

```
<div class="body">
    <ul id="teaTypesMenu">
        <li name="black-tea-nav" class="testClass">
            Black
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="black-tea-nav" class="tempMenuContainer testClass">
        This is some awesome text that you never heard of. D:
    </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#teaTypesMenu li").mouseenter(function() {

    //Get name attribute of li element
    var container_name = $(this).attr("name");
    //Show Element
    $("#" + container_name).slideDown(500);
});

$(".testClass").mouseleave(function(){
    //Hide Element
    $(".tempMenuContainer").slideUp();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a timer to give a little delay when the mouse leaves the `li` so that the user could get to the target element - This is if you cannot modify the markup

```
<div class="body">
    <ul id="teaTypesMenu">
        <li name="black-tea-nav">
            Black
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="black-tea-nav" class="tempMenuContainer testClass">
        This is some awesome text that you never heard of. D:
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#teaTypesMenu li").hover(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr("name"),
            $target = $('#' + name);
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    }, function () {
        var name = $(this).attr("name"),
            $target = $('#' + name);
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $(".testClass").hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EEndL/)

Answer (score 1):

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLpHE/1/)**

add a `:eq(1)` to your class selector for select secend .testClass and etc

```
$(".testClass:eq(1)").mouseleave(function(){
//Hide Element
$(".tempMenuContainer").slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the test class from and the same script will work

```
<div class="body">
    <ul id="teaTypesMenu">
        <li name="black-tea-nav" class="">
            Black
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

alternately if you don't want to remove the class then you may change the script to

```
$(".tempMenuContainer").mouseleave(function(){
    //Hide Element
    $(".tempMenuContainer").slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap something around it, so that the .mouseover() isn't restricted to the tea's name. It could look like this:

HTML

```
<ul class="tea-list">
    <li>
        <div class="tea">Black</div>
        <div class="more-info">I love it!</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.tea-list{
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.tea-list li{
    cursor:help;
}

.tea {
    background:silver;
    padding:10px 15px;
    margin:0;
}

.more-info{
    display:none;

    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 15px;
    margin:0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('.more-info').slideDown(500);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.more-info').slideUp(200);        
    })
})
```

jsfiddle.net/jLpHE/3/

Hope this helps - cheers!